# Debugging/Developing tool for apache's mod_rewrite (Rewrite Engine)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Is there any tool (GUI or online) for developing and debugging apache's mod_rewrite (Rewrite Engine) rules?
Something like Regex tools that get input (for example URLs per line) and some rewrite rules; Then displays rules's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rewrite log file for debugging :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteLog "/home/test/public/logs/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```

OR you can follow this detailed debugging tutorial:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html